# .Net Core JWT generation does not seem to work, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, json-web-token

I'm trying to generate a Json Web Token (JWT) using `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` and the following code:

```
public static string GenerateToken()
{
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SecretKeySecretKeySecretKeySecretKeySecretKeySecretKeySecretKeyS");
    var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key);

    var claims = new[]
    {
        new Claim("user_id", "John Doe"),
        new Claim("name", "some-guid-will-go-here"),
        new Claim("admin", "true", ClaimValueTypes.Boolean)
    };

    var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().CreateJwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: "example.com",
        audience: "example.com",
        subject: new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
        expires: now.AddMinutes(30),
        notBefore: now,
        issuedAt: now,
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256),
        encryptingCredentials: new EncryptingCredentials(securityKey, JwtConstants.DirectKeyUseAlg, SecurityAlgorithms.Aes256CbcHmacSha512)
        );

    var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);
}
```

When I run the function GenerateToken() it returns a token looking like this:

`eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2Q0JDLUhTNTEyIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0..EYFD_3JkBLjHFUPfFul-HQ.GP6QX0DAT7xb8rcvAH-1gKVKx2pUpMldHq4UkRevpPF8G7uzlcbMQQtkvavCIfrQ339bOxqBu9Sk9OOnMfq4xcsLs2v9qrlUKM7virT9wf4PcrnywO15xCQcdEFcN2ED4dbmn8mFJpE7jguvIuPHoZM6sYcjvwQS5Xl6vWBFVOFanF0EXauGOhVwmfcU5lCn4Y2cRjM7qD5WY5BuItvlsUEFcYQJsHOfupgdth-cTkTiihUU92R1lQla81WiXyGmS1hJZ4NJk87HUnBYQKBH9JHgJ-_F3x2seQkgCPLTCJmU7YFU_JR8mjlcu97Tl-BHWxn-z1EOpqPTCK1yPXZ6mYXrTy1ber0f8yd1hao9dvbwL3-u689YL3LnntNIV89L1jr0V-emvkTO2GE8k6z-YQ.kzjDt0foAswdWqTsEOPW4e8QbP4XOoKrmxJX0hBozlc`

and when I try to validate that token using jwt.io it won't work. I can't get the payload from the token and I can't use the secret to validate or decrypt the token.
Am I doing something wrong or why isn't it working? What am I missing?

Comment: The jwt you provided as an example has too many `.`s. Specifically, at `..EYFD`, it should just be a single `.`. Actually there's another extra `.` in there - there should only be 2 but you have 4.

Comment: That's strange, all the tokens I generate with the above code gets 4 `.`, I generated a few more and all of them got 2 in a row and the 2 more later on in the string.

Why's that?

Comment: Looking into this a bit more for you, the extra `.`s etc is all fine - It's because the token is encrypted. I don't think [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) supports encrypted JWTs. I've managed to to decrypt the token being generated by your code in C#, proving that the token is indeed valid.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

        ValidIssuer = (string)Configuration.GetSection("JwtToken").GetValue(typeof(string), "Issuer"),
        ValidAudience = (string)Configuration.GetSection("JwtToken").GetValue(typeof(string), "Audience"),
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SecretKeySecretKeySecretKeySecretKeySecretKeySecretKeySecretKeyS")),
        TokenDecryptionKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SecretKeySecretKeySecretKeySecretKeySecretKeySecretKeySecretKeyS")),
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0),
    };
});
```